# Highlight the current line number for the active buffer in `nlinum-mode`

Tags: emacs, highlight, line-numbers

I am using the package [nlinum](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/nlinum.html) 1.9 for showing line numbers in the margin.

In order to highlight the current line, I set the variable `(setq nlinum-highlight-current-line t)`.
It correctly works.

However, if I have multiple windows in my frame I would like to only highlight the line of the active window.

The current behavior:
[image]

The left window is active, but the line 5 is highlighted for the right windows too.

Comment: It's a known limitation in the code.  Patch welcome.

Comment: @Stefan [Done. Pull request created on git](https://github.com/emacsmirror/nlinum/pull/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use hlinum "https://github.com/tom-tan/hlinum-mode" 
that is an linum-mode extension to highlight current line number.
Simple add this 2 lines to your .emacs

```
(require 'hlinum)
(hlinum-activate)
```

[image: example (both buffer on line 42)]